# Using Pod install RealmSwift show Downloading core failed

Tags: ios, core-data, realm

I already try many time and My Internet connection is very fastly!

[image]

Comment: This can happen if you have a poor internet connection,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are In China,a lot of Website have been BAN.

1) Use VPN

2) go to  https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ download zip manual install